# Bash Script not taking FileName as command line argument

Tags: bash, command-line

I am new in bash.. Here is my code for bash script which will take file name as command line argument 
Code of file hello is :-

```
#!/bin/bash    
if ["$1"!= "abcd.txt"]; then
   echo Good
else
   echo Not Good
fi
```

when i am running

```
$hello abcd.txt
```

It's showing

```
/usr/bin/hello: line 2: [abcd.txt: command not found
Not Good
```

Where is the problem? Please help me as soon as possible. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`["$1"!= "abcd.txt"]` is not syntactically right.

You need spaces after `[`, before `]` and also before `!=`:

```
[ "$1" != "abcd.txt" ]
```

Comment: To clarify why this is needed you should know that `[` is a command and needs `]` to be the last argument, while each other part should be an its own argument. These days however `[` is for the most part a build in.